Prove that $(k+j)!\leq 2^{k+j}k!j!$
I'm working through a list of problems regarding multi-index notation and there's an odd inequality that I'm trying to prove.
$$(k+j)!\leq 2^{k+j}k!j!\quad \forall j,k \in \mathbb{N}.$$
I'm going for induction on $k+j$. For $k+j=0$, the statement is true, so let's assume that the inequality holds for $k+j=N-1$ and try to prove that it holds for $N$ as well. My approach uses a previous exercise that claims that
$$2^N=\sum_{j+k=N} \frac{N!}{k!j!},\quad \text{which follows from } \quad x^N=\sum_{|\alpha|=N} \frac{N!}{\alpha!}$$.
Here's my attempt. Let $\alpha=(k,j)$ and $|\alpha|=N$. Also, let $\beta$ be a multi-index such that $|\beta|=N-1$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(k+j)!=N!=N\cdot (N-1)! &\leq& N \cdot \left(2^{N-1} \beta !\right) \\
     &=& N\left[\left(\sum_{|\gamma|=N-1} \dfrac{(N-1)!}{\gamma!}\right)\beta !\right]\\
     &=& \sum_{|\gamma|=N-1} \dfrac{N!}{\gamma!}\beta !.
\end{eqnarray*}
I'm stuck at this point. Is there any useful relation between $\beta$ and $\gamma$ knowing that $|\gamma|=|\beta|=N-1$?

You can divided both sides by $k!$ and $j!$. The left-hand side then becomes $\binom{k+j}{k}$. This is less than $2^{k+j}$ because $\sum_{i=0}^{k+j} \binom{k+j}{i} = 2^{k+j}$.

Or, $\binom{k+j}{k}$ is the number of subsets of ${ 1, \ldots, k+j }$ of size $k$, and $2^{k+j}$ is the number of all subsets of ${ 1, \ldots, k+j }$.

Wow, such a cleaner approach. Though, I wonder why such a thing was put in the middle of a multi-index list of problems. Does anyone know about applications regarding this inequality?

@vshp11 Not totally sure, but it could come in handy to prove other inequalities. Is your list of problems from a textbook?

There is a simple combinatorial argument. If you rearrange a bit, you can compare $\binom{j + k}{j}$ with $2^{j + k}$. It is a well-known combinatorial identity that $\sum_{r = 0}^N \binom{N}{r} = 2^N$. Since all terms in the summation are non-negative (in fact, positive),
$$\binom{j + k}{j} \le 2^{j + k} \implies \frac{(j + k)!}{j! k!} \le 2^{j + k} \implies (j + k)! \le 2^{j + k} j! k!$$
as desired.
